# Order XmlNodeList based on an attribute

Tags: c#, xml

I have an *XmlNodeList* that contains packets (item) from the root of the XML example below. I want to sort the XmlNodeList based on the *node's key attribute value*.
The sorting has to be very efficient, every millisecond counts.

Do you have any idea?

```
<root>
    <item key="1000000020">
        Content 20
    </item>
    <item key="1000000001">
        Content 1
    </item>
    ...
    <item key="1043245231">
        Content n
    </item>
</root>
```

Edit: 
I already have an XmlNodeList constructed from the items. I do not have access to the XmlDocument anymore, only the list of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in a very non-elegant way:

- I iterated my *XmlNodeList*
- During iteration I extracted the timestamps
- After extracting a timestamp I added the timestamp-XmlElement to a  *SortedDictionary*
- Converted the SortedDictionary to list (*sortedKeys = sortedByDateDisctionary.Keys.ToList();*)
- If the nodes need to be sorted Descending then *sortedKeys.Reverse();*
- Then the nodes can be accessed by the sorted keys

Comment: What if more than one nodes have same time stamp ?

Answer (score 4):

note: xml variable is string value

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

IEnumerable<XmlNode> rows = doc.SelectNodes("report/table/row").Cast<XmlNode>().OrderByDescending(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Attributes["conversions"].Value));
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try Linq to XML.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);

   var nodeList = from ele in doc.Descendants("item")
                   orderby int.Parse(ele.Attribute("key").Value)
                   select ele;
```

You may try `XPathNavigator` and `XPathExpression`.

```
 //I presume that variable xNodeList contains XmlNodeList.
  XPathNavigator nav=xNodeList.Item(0).OwnerDocument.CreateNavigator();
  XPathExpression exp = nav.Compile("root/item");


  exp.AddSort("@key", XmlSortOrder.Ascending, XmlCaseOrder.None, "", XmlDataType.Number );

  foreach (XPathNavigator t in nav.Select(exp))
  {
    Console.WriteLine(t.OuterXml );
   }
```

Comment: This would be very elegant, but will not do because I don't have access to the XmlDocument, just the XmlNodeList.

Comment: @Germstorm - You may try XPathExpression and XPathNavigator. See I'v update my post.